# How do make SolrField, multiValue as false using C#

Tags: c#, solr, solrnet

I used the below snippet

```
class Program
{
    public class Product
    {
        [SolrField("id")]
        public string id { get; set; }

        [SolrField("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Startup.Init<Product>("http://localhost:8983/solr/product");

        ISolrOperations<Product> solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Product>>();
        Product test = new Product() { id = "changeme2", title = "changeme2" };
        solr.Add(test);
        solr.Commit();

        SolrQueryResults<Product> results = solr.Query(new SolrQuery("id:\"changeme2\""));
        foreach (Product result in results)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(result.title);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

But the output in Solr is

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "zkConnected":true,
    "status":0,
    "QTime":11,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1566890226119"}},
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"maxScore":1.0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"changeme2",
        "title":["changeme2"],
        "_version_":1643001803678154752}]
  }}
```

In the above "title" is stored as ArrayList. But Since i declared as string. I want to be only String. Using C# how do will i achieve this.

Comment: Can you provide your  `title` field declaration in schema?

Answer (score 0):

That's [not going to work](https://github.com/SolrNet/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Mapping.md), since updating the Solr schema is a separate process and in many cases require reindexing your content. SolrNet explicitly says they're not doing (or planning to do) schema modifications:

> Solr fields defined in your schema.xml must be mapped to properties in a .NET class. SolrNet does not write the schema.xml based on .NET code. It's up to you to keep this in sync. Note that sometimes you might not want to have things exactly in sync, as some fields might be represented differently in .NET and Solr or you might want to have additional fields in Solr for other use cases.

You can update the Schema either by [editing the `schema.xml` file](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/defining-fields.html#defining-fields), or by using the [Schema API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/schema-api.html). If you're [using the schemaless mode](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_1/schemaless-mode.html) (which is fine for prototyping), all fields will be multivalued by default.